# Scrapy XmlFeedSpider based on String Argument - How to Suppress Automatic Request

Tags: python, scrapy

**Aim:** Trigger the execution of an XMLFeedSpider by passing the response as an argument (i.e. no need for start_urls).

Example Command:

```
scrapy crawl spider_name -a response_as_string="<xml><sometag>abc123</sometag></xml>"
```

Example Spider:

```
class ExampleXmlSpider(XMLFeedSpider):

    name = "spider_name"
    itertag = 'sometag'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        response2 = XmlResponse(url="Some URL", body=self.response_as_string)
        ProcessResponse().get_data(response2)

    def __init__(self, response_as_string=''):
        self.response_as_string = response_as_string
```

**Problem:** Terminal complains that there is no start_urls. I can only get the above to work if I include a dummy.xml within start_urls.

E.g.

```
start_urls = ['file:///home/user/dummy.xml']
```

**Question:** Is there anyway to have an XMLFeedSpider that is purely driven by a response provided by an argument (as per the original command)? In which case I would need to suppress the need for the XMLFeedSpider to seek out a start_url to execute a request.

Comment: I'm not sure Scrapy is what you need here, if you already have the data as string, to be used as input. Do you need a Spider to do what you need? You could cook up a python script, taking a string argument with the XML data and use anything to parse the XML (including Scrapy if you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Paul, you were spot on. Updated example code below. I stopped referring to the class as an XMLFeedSpider. Python script updated to be a class of type "object" with the ability to pass the url and body as arguments.

```
from scrapy.http import XmlResponse    

class ExampleXmlSpider(object):

        def __init__(self, response_url='', response_body=''):
            self. response_url = response_url
            self.response_body = response_body

        def run(self):
            response = XmlResponse(url=self.response_url, body=self.response_body)
            print response.url
```